# How do I create a unix script to create multiple GNU screens?

Tags: gnu-screen

In .screenrc, I can have the lines:

```
screen -t title1 command1
screen -t title2 command2
```

I would like to create a batch file to add a few screens at once, what is the best way of going about that?

If I just run those two commands in a single batch file, I get screen start with command 1, but command 2 only executes when I exit the screen process.

An ampersand might do it but be a bit untidy, but I was wondering if there's a better method?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the goals behind this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have several environments, production, dev, uat - at work.  I would like to run one command to initiate 3 screens, in a scripted file.  I found that calling screen like above, the flow of control is halted by screen itself, and it's only upon exiting the second line runs.  The idea of using a config file below looks like the best way of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a script to generate a new .screenrc file which adds enough screens to run what you want.

Your script could then launch `screen` after generating the .screenrc.

Comment: Additional note, you don't have to overwrite `~/.screenrc` either, you can specify a temporary file as the config file when starting `screen`.